# ReSharper big font in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

not sure if that big font comes from my Windows 10 setting or ReSharper still is not fully integrated with Visual Studio 2015. Does anyone else have the same problem?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resharper allows you to either use the `Visual Studio IntelliSense font` or the `Text Editor font` (under `Resharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`IntelliSense`->`Completion Appearance`)

The `Visual Studio Intellisense font` is set in Visual Studio by: `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Fonts and Colors` and change setting for `Statement Completion`

(Or you could uninstall Xamarin tools...)

Comment: lol thanks I don't know why it messed with my Intellisense font size

Comment: I have the same problem, changing font size in `Tools->Options...->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Statement Completion` gives the effect, but if font size is 9, it is broken, how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

`Extensions >> Resharper >> Options`
`Environment >> IntelliSense >> Completion Appearance >> Display completion items in:` 
Select `**Text Editor font**`